# Can I use something other than an input type="submit" to send a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is my html code for my little form. The way my 'submit button is styled it can only be an `<a>`. Can I still submit this form to an email? How can I make this send to the email assigned to it? jQuery or Javascript?

For example can I use this:

```
<a class="btn send" href="#send">Send</a>
```

versus `input type="submit"`?

```
<form action="mailto:me@myemail.com">
     <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name" required/><br>
     <input name="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" required/><br>
     <textarea class="message" maxlength="200" placeholder="We can answer your questions." required><?php echo $_POST[message]; ?></textarea><br>
     <a class="btn send" href="#send"><img src="img/send.png" /></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Or anything that has an `onclick` event that you can call `.submit()` on the form element.

Comment: You can use any element you want as long as you attach the submit event to it.

Comment: Why can't you style the button to look like you want it?

Comment: Is the only way for me to send this contact form to my email through PHP? Or can it be done quick and easy through javascript?

Comment: If you want the user to click something and have the email be sent with no further trouble, then yes you need to do it at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<button type=submit>Submit Me!</button>
```

Also "image" buttons submit forms.

Now, that said, you cannot directly initiate an email transaction from an HTML form. The best you can do is cause the user's mailer to be shown, but you have precious little control over how/if that works.

Comment: Also good to know that the `type` for `<button>` defaults to `submit`.

Comment: @Esailija yes but not always - old IE defaulted to "button"

Comment: I see... that was much better and more intuitive. I've answered at least 3 posts that had a bug because of the implicit `type=submit` :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically submit the form:

```
$(".btn.send").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
    return false;
});
```

Or since you use image, how about simple `<input type="image">`:

```
<input type="image" src="img/send.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better...

```
$('#AnyElement').click(function() {
 $('#formID').submit();
});
```